gRPC: A long-lived stream service (CallbackService) OnCancel never called
I implemented a long-lived stream service:
 class McaPwrBtnService final : public peripheral::PowerButton::CallbackService
The rpc is implemented like:
grpc::ServerWriteReactor<peripheral::KeyEvent>* McaPwrBtnService::listenForKeyEvents( ::grpc::CallbackServerContext* ctx, const ::google::protobuf::Empty*)
{
    class Listener : public grpc::ServerWriteReactor<peripheral::KeyEvent> {


As long only one client is connected everything works fine.
When the client exits, ServerWriteReactor::OnCancel gets called
When a second client connects, ServerWriteReactor::OnCancel never gets called anymore, when the both clients terminate. Further more, from that moment on, the server doesn't accept any RPCs anymore.
If checked my code several times, compared it with the examples.
Couldn't find anything wrong.
My questions:

is my approach wrong?
Could this be a gRPC bug?

BR
Nik

subsequenty i tested grpc/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_callback_server/client
The same issue can bee observed.
But I have noticed that the problem only occurs on the target, but not on my Ubuntu Desktop PC.
Linux ubuntu2004 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
The target system is an embedded Yocto linux ( kirkstone) on imx8x CPU
Linux ccimx8x-30020004xx 5.15.71-dey+g93a4ac021755 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 7 09:07:04 UTC 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
